# Paypal IPN gets failed in Nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, paypal, paypal-ipn, nopcommerce

I have created Nopcommerce website at local IIS with static IP address which is accessible publicly & port number of that IP is 8002.

I have used paypalstandard plugin. But issue is paypal IPN gets failed.
Please help to get paypal IPN worked.

Is the paypal IPN works only for port80/443??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in this article about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).

Comment: Ok. but it works fine at first time.then after it stopped.

Comment: Then you need to run tests to figure out why/where it stopped.  That's what that link covers.

Comment: Nothing has change on my website yet IPN is being reported as failed. Payments going thru  but notification isn't. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If you would follow the instructions in the article I linked you to you would find the error.  I don't know what else to tell you if you're not willing to do that.